# stop all sounds in Web Audio API

Tags: web-audio-api

I loaded and played multiple sounds with web audio api at the same time. Is there any way to stop all sounds?

ex: a button to stop all sounds now.

Since I have more than 10 sounds playing at the same time, I dont wanna manually use noteOff(0) (or stop(0) ) for each sound source.

Comment: can you please tell me how to use gain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve the effect you want, then, is to connect() them all to a gain node which is then connected to the destination, and set gain.gain.value = 0.

It won't actually stop them, of course, but it will silence them.

Comment: yea I googled around and this may be a better choice. Otherwise I would use an array to loop through the elements and stop them.

Comment: @cwilso can please explain me how to use gain to stop all audio or mute all audio and again play them please